# Import and Export using OS in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I want to import all data using path but I keep getting error. And how can I get an output in a separate file?

**Input File:**

```
import os,json
path= "./Responses"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open (file) as json_file:
        data=json.load(json_file)
```

**Error Message:**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data_1.json'
```

And can I separate the new data by using 'Out'?

**Output File:**

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(json_data, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump('Out'+ data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got error because python script cannot find the relative path for the file founded in "with open (file) as json_file:"

To fix that you can change that to:

```
 with open (path +'/'+ file) as json_file:
```